# Ubuntu Bluetooth device config file location

Tags: gnome, bluetooth

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 with GNOME. I had a pair of Bluetooth headphones that I lost and replaced with new ones, and I am stuck trying to figure out how to remove the old ones, or even just reset the entire Bluetooth device list. I tried the command line tools and the standard user interface, but my old headphones stay on the list no matter what.

Is there a file or group of files I can delete to force the Bluetooth stack to reset back to a 'factory state'?